# Why is my PHP conditional statement not working properly?

Tags: php, if-statement

The purpose of the PHP code below is to create a math quiz consisting of two questions. The user will answer the two questions and click on the submit button.

After clicking the submit button, the user's answers will be compared with the right answers (each question will be compared separately) then the total score `$totalScore` is calculated.

Finally, the user's data will be inserted into the database then the user will be directed to a different webpage.

The only problem I have is the value for `$totalscore`, this value is either 1 or 0, whether the user answers all the questions right or wrong. it's random. i don't know why.

- the value for `$totalscore` should be = 2 if user answers the two questions correctly
- the value for `$totalscor`e should be = 1 if user answers one of the questions correctly
- the value for `$totalscore` should be = 0 if user answers the two questions incorrectly

But that is not the case. please help

```
<?php

get_header();

//GENERATING SOME RANDOM NUMBERS
$number1 = rand(1, 10); // Generate a random number between 1 and 10
$number2 = rand(1, 10); // Generate another random number between 1 and 10
$number3 = rand(1, 10); // Generate another random number between 1 and 10
$number4 = rand(1, 10); // Generate another random number between 1 and 10

// Calculate the answers for the two questions
$answer1 = $number1 + $number2;
$answer2 = $number3 + $number4;

$totalScore = 0; // Initialize total score
?>

<form method="post">
    <p>Question 1: What is <?php echo $number1; ?> + <?php echo $number2; ?>?</p>
    <input type="text" name="answerIn1" placeholder="Enter your answer" required><br>

    <p>Question 2: What is <?php echo $number3; ?> + <?php echo $number4; ?>?</p>
    <input type="text" name="answerIn2" placeholder="Enter your answer" required><br>

    <div class="centered-container-ForSubmitBtn">
        <input type="submit" name="submit_answer" value="Submit" style="border: 1px solid;">
    </div>
</form>

<?php
// Check if the form has been submitted
if (isset($_POST['submit_answer'])) {
    $userAnswers1 = $_POST['answerIn1']; // Get the user's answers from the submitted form for Q1
    $userAnswers2 = $_POST['answerIn2']; // Get the user's answers from the submitted form for Q2

    $user_name = $_SESSION['user_name']; // Retrieve the username from the session

    if ($userAnswers1 == $answer1) {
        $totalScore = $totalScore + 1;
    }

    if ($userAnswers2 == $answer2) {
        $totalScore = $totalScore + 1;
    }

    global $wpdb; // Access the global $wpdb object
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'My_user_test_info'; // Prefix the table name with the WordPress prefix

    // Prepare and execute the SQL query to insert the data into the database
    $data = array(
        'user_names' => $user_name,
        'test_scores' => $totalScore);
    $wpdb->insert($table_name, $data);

    //Direct the user to a different webpage
    wp_redirect(admin_url('/results-page/'));
}

?>


<?php
get_footer();
?>
```

I don't have any other problems except for the one mentioned above.

Comment: You are not keeping track/storing the original numbers. These will change with every request, `$number1 = rand(1, 10);`, making it impossible to track/verify if any user gave the correct answer

Comment: Before blaming the conditional statement, you should echo the variables you're testing.

Comment: you should send the old rand number variable with the form when you submit it. Technically when you load the page the n1 and n2 are different from the number you compare after submitting the form. Send old numbers in your post request and then compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your numbers is getting changed every time user submits the form. You will need to store the numbers in session for matching with the users input.

The final code will look like this.

```
<?php
session_start();
get_header();
// Check if the form has been submitted
if (isset($_POST['submit_answer'])) {
    $totalScore = 0; // Initialize total score
    $userAnswers1 = $_POST['answerIn1']; // Get the user's answers from the submitted form for Q1
    $userAnswers2 = $_POST['answerIn2']; // Get the user's answers from the submitted form for Q2

    $user_name = $_SESSION['user_name']; // Retrieve the username from the session

    if ($userAnswers1 == $_SESSION['answer1']) {
        $totalScore = $totalScore + 1;
    }

    if ($userAnswers2 == $_SESSION['answer2']) {
        $totalScore = $totalScore + 1;
    }

    global $wpdb; // Access the global $wpdb object
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'My_user_test_info'; // Prefix the table name with the WordPress prefix

    // Prepare and execute the SQL query to insert the data into the database
    $data = array(
        'user_names' => $user_name,
        'test_scores' => $totalScore);
    $wpdb->insert($table_name, $data);

    //Direct the user to a different webpage
    wp_redirect(admin_url('/results-page/'));

}else{
  //GENERATING SOME RANDOM NUMBERS
  $number1 = rand(1, 10); // Generate a random number between 1 and 10
  $number2 = rand(1, 10); // Generate another random number between 1 and 10
  $number3 = rand(1, 10); // Generate another random number between 1 and 10
  $number4 = rand(1, 10); // Generate another random number between 1 and 10

  // Calculate the answers for the two questions
  $answer1 = $number1 + $number2;
  $answer2 = $number3 + $number4;
  $_SESSION['answer1'] = $answer1;
  $_SESSION['answer2'] = $answer2;
}

?>

<form method="post">
    <p>Question 1: What is <?php echo $number1; ?> + <?php echo $number2; ?>?</p>
    <input type="text" name="answerIn1" placeholder="Enter your answer" required><br>

    <p>Question 2: What is <?php echo $number3; ?> + <?php echo $number4; ?>?</p>
    <input type="text" name="answerIn2" placeholder="Enter your answer" required><br>

    <div class="centered-container-ForSubmitBtn">
        <input type="submit" name="submit_answer" value="Submit" style="border: 1px solid;">
    </div>
</form>

<?php
get_footer();
?>
```

Comment: Thank you Ashis Kumar, and everyone else. That fixed my problem. You guys are 10X better than ChatGPT